# Dynamic select LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a query like so, but I want to be able to dynamically select.

Is it possible to user a variable to select, so that instead of `X` you can use something like `string x = "cat"`

And it will then select all cats

```
var Query = from a in db.MyDb
            where a.Id.Equals(UserId)
            select a.Animal.X;
```

Comment: I answered a similar question in detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382440/ef-linq-query-with-conditional-include/29383117#29383117

Answer (score 0):

You can do the dynamic select - if the selected properties have the same type.

Let's have a look at a simplified example:

```
    class Animal
    {
        public string Cat { get; set; }
        public string Dog { get; set; }
        public int PropertyWithDifferentType { get; set; }
    }

    var animals = new List<Animal>();
    animals.Add(new Animal { Cat = "cat", Dog = "a dog", 
        PropertyWithDifferentType = 42 });
```

A simple dynamic select can be done like this:

```
var selector  = 0;
var result = animals.Select(a => (selector == 0) ? a.Dog : a.Cat);
```

However, the following statement will give an compile error because of different types:

```
 var doesNotCompile = animals.Select(a => (selector == 0) ? a.Dog : a.PropertyWithDifferentType);
```

If the dynamic select is larger expression you may want to define a function for it like:

```
Func<string> myPropertySelector(Animal a, int selector) {
    switch (selector) {
            case 0: return () => a.Dog;
            default: return ()=> a.Cat;
    }
}
```

An example usage is:

```
var result = animals.Select(a => myPropertySelector(a, selector));
```

Putting it all together your query can look like this (I personally prefer the method syntax):

```
var Query = db.MyDb
           .Where(a => a.Id == UserId)
           .Select(a => myPropertySelector(a.Animal, selector));
```